# How to get Kerberos default principal

Tags: python, bash, shell, terminal, kerberos

if I type `kinit` into my terminal:

```
kinit
```

...then I get the following Kerberos authentication prompt:

```
Password for JayFrizzle@ANT.STACKOVERFLOW.COM:
```

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to programatically get the `username@DOMAIN.COM` string via the shell (or python)?  `kinit` somehow knows who the default user is (in my case, JayFrizzle).  Is there a way I can get this information, either via calling Kerberos orfrom a preexisting file on my computer?

Comment: Is `JayFrizzle` you local username? Because that is what `kinit` uses by default.

Comment: `klist` should give you list of principals. You can just `grep` the results for what you want.

Comment: @chrisaycock  I thought this would work too, but if you don't have any tickets (or if they all expired) then you won't see any usernames.  `kdestroy && klist` would show you what I'm talking about

Comment: @larsks Valid point, I never thought of that.  Do you know how I can get the domain?  I'm working on an application that needs to be cross compatible in three different ANT.somedomain.COM domains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no reliable mechanism by which you can determine the Kerberos principal of a user *before* they have acquired a valid Kerberos ticket.

As I mentioned in the comment, `kinit` will use your local username as the username portion of your Kerberos principal.  But: there's no guarantee that this is correct; it's entirely possible that someone may always `kinit` with an explicit username that differs from their local username.

And it's even trickier than that: depending on the local system configuration, `kinit` may not even be involved in acquiring a Kerberos token.  For example, the [sssd](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/) authentication service supports Kerberos natively, and has its own configuration that is completely separate from that used by the MIT (or Heimdal) Kerberos packages.

SSSD allows for mapping between local usernames and Kerberos principal names (so that, for example, when you log into your local system as JayFrizzle you will automatically acquire a Kerberos ticket for jayf@EXAMPLE.COM).

This also means that determining the Kerberos domain isn't really possible, either.  If you're just using the MIT kerberos tools, you could in theory parse the default domain out of `/etc/krb5.conf`...but again, this may or may not actually be correct (because the user can specify an explicit domain name when running `kinit`).

So if you know your environment, and you know you're only relying on the traditional MIT kerberos command line tools, you can use the local username and the default domain from `/etc/krb5.conf` to get the information you want.

But realistically, you should just require that the user acquire credentials via some other means, and then use `klist` or some programmatic analog to get the principal name.

Comment: In my scenario, users will be using the default domain listed in their `/etc/krb5.conf` (thanks for mentioning that file), so using that coupled with getpass.getuser() works for us.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try with oklist command it will display default principal like below.

> 

Default principal: user@DOMAIN.COM

> 

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).